# Actualizar rama con git

Tags: git

Estoy trabajando en una rama y no esta actualizada a la actual, muestro como esta la estructura.

```
main
|
| \
|  usuarioUno
| /
| \
|  mi_rama
| /
|
|main
```

El `usuarioUno` actualizo código y en `mi_rama` no puedo actualizarlo. Si bien ya hice un pull, pero no logro que actualizar el código.

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de solucionar este problema pero en mi caso yo haría un **rebase** de **mi_rama** con main y así **mi_rama** tendrá todos los cambios de main y su código deberia funcionar con algo como lo siguiente

```
# primero nos movemos a la rama que esta atrasada
> git checkout mi_rama

# Despues Hacemos el rebase a main o a la rama que queramos
> git rebase -i master
```

Al terminar este proceso deberias poder ver algo como esto en tu branch log

```
main
|
| \
|  usuarioUno
| /
| \
|  mi_rama
| /
```

**Nota:** hay probabilidad de que esto genere conflictos pero puedes arreglarlos manualmente

Referencias que puedes consultar:

- [Documentación oficial](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)
- [Ejemplo FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/la-guia-definitiva-para-git-merge-y-git-rebase/#:%7E:text=Para%20usar%20git%20rebase%20en,empezar%20a%20editar%20la%20prueba.)
- [Ejemplo de Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)